# Dash keeps showing old graph

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am running dash to get the camera settings for a plotly 3d scatter graph. My issue is that the code keeps showing the old graphs and it does not the new graphs on the server Dash `http://127.0.0.1:8050/`

So on my jupyter notebook the 3d scatter plot shows up nicely but not when clicking on the `http://127.0.0.1:8050/` link. In that case an old 3dscatter plot is shown.

So how can I clean up the cache? Or find the file that is linked to the

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import html
    
# Create a 3D scatter plot
fig = go.Figure()
    
# Scatter plots for dataframes 1, 2, and 3
for df, color in zip([df_nearest_cp1, df_nearest_cp2, df_nearest_cp3,df_nearest_cp4], ['blue', 'blue', 'blue','blue']):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
        x=df['X_AC_900']-50853, y=df['Y_AC_900'], z=df['Z_AC_900'],
        mode='markers', marker=dict(size=1, color=color),
        name='V534-73873-200-00_B00'))
    
# Scatter plot for dataframe 4
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
    x=df_defect_test['X_AC_drw-900']-50853, y=df_defect_test['Y_AC_drw-900'], z=df_defect_test['Z_AC_drw-900'],
    mode='markers', marker=dict(size=5, color='red'),
    name="p - af - c77-str24.2-1"))
    
# Set camera positions
eye_x=0
eye_y=0
eye_z=0
    
center_x=0+10
camera_positions = [
    dict(
        eye={'x': -0.4872106294039529, 'y': 1.067201999150249, 'z': 1.687107596216643},
        center={'x': 1.2277721767123837, 'y': 1.36809186831154, 'z': 1.5427352345507372},
        up={'x': 0.19025028657504267, 'y': -0.9201266584975012, 'z': 0.3423036090670629}
    ),
    # Add more camera positions as needed
]
    
for i, position in enumerate(camera_positions):
        
    fig.update_layout(scene=dict(camera=position), title=f'Image {i+1}')
fig.update_scenes(aspectmode='data')
# Show the plot
fig.show()
    
for df, color in zip([df_part1, df_part2, df_part3,df_part4], ['blue', 'blue', 'blue','blue']):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
        x=df['X_AC_900']-50853, y=df['Y_AC_900'], z=df['Z_AC_900'],
        mode='markers', marker=dict(size=1, color=color),
        name='Points'))
fig.update_scenes(aspectmode='data')    
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id="output"),        # use to print current relayout values
    dcc.Graph(id="fig", figure=fig)
])
    
    
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("fig", "relayoutData")
)
def show_data(data):
    # show camera settings like eye upon change
    return [str(data)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=3003)
    
app.run_server(debug=False, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: At the end of your code, the server is running on the port `3003` and not at `8050`. Is this an error?